# Customer multiselect attribute selections not saving - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, multiselect-attribute

I have successfully added a multiselect attribute to the adminhtml customer edit form, but when saving the customer the selected values are not saved.

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customattribute', [
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
    'input' => 'multiselect',
    'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
    'source' => 'My\Module\Model\Config\Source\CustomOptions',
    'required' => false,
    'visible' => true,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'sort_order' => 1000,
    'position' => 1000,
    'system' => 0,
]);
```

EDIT:

The source class:

```
class PortalCategoryOptions extends AbstractSource {
    protected $_categoryHelper;

    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(Category $catalogCategory, CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory) {
        $this->_categoryHelper = $catalogCategory;
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true) {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setOrder('name');

        return $collection;
    }

    public function getAllOptions() {
        $arr = $this->toArray();
        $ret = [];

        foreach ($arr as $key => $value)  {
            $ret[] = [
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => $value
            ];
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    public function toArray() {
        $categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true,false,true);

        $categoryList = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category){
            if ($category->getEntityId() >= 3) {
                $categoryList[$category->getEntityId()] = __($category->getName());
            }
        }

        return $categoryList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show further code which you used to add attribute in customer edit form?

Comment: I have added the rest of the code, but I don't think it's relevant since that part of the code works fine.

Comment: I am asking for the code, which you write to add above customer attribute in customer edit section.

Comment: Can you finaly solve this? i have the same issue

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136981)